# Creating Flutter version for wordpress woocomerce website using flutter widget for login and the rest as WebView i have problem with dataflow

Tags: wordpress, flutter, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am making a flutter version of the WP WC website i created the login and register part in flutter and when then you get into the WebView due to time issues .
1- how do i use the API for auth?
2- how do i get into the webview logged in with the same data?

I was thinking about creating a cookie from the log in and push it into the webview.
But the ideal solution is to send data in some sort of a link or API that will get webView as if we logged in from the logged in page if that make sense.